# Selenium: Click on dropdown is not working

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I am trying to use selenium click to open dropdown menu and then click again to download a file. Common error I get is that the "element is not attached to the page document" Have tried different codes but here's one:

```
#button = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//ul[@class="dropdown-menu-right dropdown-menu"]')
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
element = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "options-dropdown")))
element.click()
```

HTML snapshot:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Generally `<ul>` nodes along with it's decendent `<li>` nodes gets expanded clicking on `<span>` nodes.

---

### Solution

To click and open the [drop-down-menu](/questions/tagged/drop-down-menu) i.e. to expand the `<li>` nodes you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for the [*element_to_be_clickable()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54194511/7429447) and you can use either of the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48056120/7429447):

- Using *CSS_SELECTOR*:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "span.dropdown-toggle#options-dropdown"))).click()
  ```
- Using *XPATH*:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//span[@class='dropdown-toggle' and @id='options-dropdown']"))).click()
  ```
- **Note**: You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```